# Choose the value of k that makes the following function continuous at x = -6

Tags: limits

$$\begin{cases}
kx + 8 & x < -6\\
-9x + k & x \geq -6
\end{cases}$$

**When I did my work**

$$kx+8 = -9x+k\\
k(-6)+8 = -9(-6)+k\\
k(-6)+8 = 54+k\\
k(-6) = 46+k$$

How do I go from here?

Comment: kx + 8 and -9x + k  For what values of $x$?

Comment: kx + 8 when x < -6 and -9x + k when x > or equal to -6.

Comment: Please edit your question with this information. It's bad form if half the question is in the comments.

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to this site. I added that to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an equation for $k$. The equation is

$$-6k = 46 + k$$

You can solve this equation for $k$ and you will get your solution.

The more important thing is to know where your equation came from. The thing is that your function is equal to $kx+8$ for $x<6$, meaning that the limit

$$\lim_{x\uparrow -6} f(x)$$

is equal to $$\lim_{x\uparrow -6} kx+8 = k\cdot (-6) + 8$$

while the upper limit $$\lim_{x\downarrow -6} f(x)$$

is (because $f(x)=-9x+k$ for $k>-6$) equal to

$$\lim_{x\downarrow -6} -9x+k = -9\cdot(-6)+k$$

and the function can only be continuous if these limits are equal.

Comment: Sorry I have brain lapses, you put the -6 infront which made my brain start clicking again. -9.2

Comment: Ok Thank you. I had the problem correct when I was randomly inputting items until I was close, but never put it into fraction form, that is why the website marked it as wrong. Also instead of dividing 7 by 46 I divided 5 by 46. Simple addition error on my part.

Comment: @beginningprogrammer Yeah, from $-6k=46+k$, you get $-7k=46$, since the plus flips to a minus.

Comment: I appreciate it